# android filewriter error and app exits

Tags: java, android, filewriter

I tried to use this Code fof writing a File, but it doesn't work:
(I also added the permission)

```
public void save(View view){
try{
        String data = " This content will append to the end of the file";
        File file =new File("javaio-appendfile.txt");
        //if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        //true = append file
        FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);
            BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
            bufferWritter.write(data);
            bufferWritter.close();
        System.out.println("Done");
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Comment: No error in eclipse it's when i compile and run the save method

Comment: Please check the path of the file. I think you have a wrong path. Try to create the file on external storage.

Comment: @codo your subject says "android filewriter error and app exits" then what's the issue?

Comment: It means that if i click the button "side stopped"